# Pass values from observableArray to another without referencing to each other

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to pass values from one `observableArray` to another one without a reference to each other, right know if I change one of the observable array values they synchronize and both have the same value.

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/B3K6V/)

**JavaScript**:

```
var test = ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3]);
var test2 = ko.observableArray(test());
test2()[0] = 2;
console.log(test());
console.log(test2());
```

**Output:**

```
[2,2,3]
[2,2,3]
```

**Expected:**

```
[1,2,3]
[2,2,3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
var test2 = ko.observableArray(test().slice(0));
```

Instead of this:

```
var test2 = ko.observableArray(test());
```

This is a simple way of creating a clone of the underlying array; right now you're referencing the same array.

The `slice` function basically selects the elements starting at the given index (0 in this case) and ends at the end of the array's length (since it isn't specified) as a new array.

From [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html):

> The slice function is the observableArray equivalent of the native
>   JavaScript slice function (i.e., it returns the entries of your array
>   from a given start index up to a given end index). Calling
>   myObservableArray.slice(...) is equivalent to calling the same method
>   on the underlying array (i.e., myObservableArray().slice(...)).

Here's an update to your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3K6V/1/).

Comment: Nice, is this intentional from knockout or is this javascript specific?

Comment: I've added a comment explaining the `slice` function.

Comment: This is intentional and a feature of knockout

Comment: @PWKad Is there any documentation why is this intentional, maybe I could use this somewhere?

Comment: @skmasq - added a source for this again. By calling `test()` you are returning the underlying array.

Comment: I'm really sorry about my ignorance, but I just can't understand what is the difference between underlying array and sliced array from underlying array? Is it that underlying array is somewhat modified and  contains a reference which only another obervable array can see?

Comment: A knockout observable array isn't really an array.  It's a function that returns the underlying array. So, when I call test() I get a reference to the underlying array.  In order to make a new object or "clone" it instead of just referencing it we use `slice` on the underlying array in order to produce a new array which has the same elements of the previous array.  Does this help?

Comment: Yes! Now I understand, I was mixed up in my head about this. Thank you! I don't understand how I didn't see this before...

Comment: Check the official documentation...  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html